# Using MVC Ajax with partial view and setting UpdateTargetId

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, actionlink, ajaxhelper

A conundrum I am trying to solve looks like this:

Say we have a view the displays a list of buttons, When a button is clicked it can do two thing:

1. go to the next list of buttons
2. open an edit form

The entire from containing the list of buttons is actually a partial view called by the parent to be loaded into a modal dialog div container:

so here is the code for the partial _ButtonListForm:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="buttonsContainer">

@foreach (var item in Model.CategoryTypesList.ListItems)
{
    var ajaxDialogoptions = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "???",
        OnComplete = "OpenDialog('???');"
    };
    @Ajax.ActionLink(item.ListItemName, item.MainItemActionButton.ActionName, item.MainItemActionButton.ControllerName, item.MainItemActionButton.RoutValues, ajaxDialogoptions, new { Class = "btn btn-large btn-info btn-block" })
}
</div>
```

I cannot set the `UpdateTargetId` to `buttonsContainer` because then it will load the entire view with another `buttonsContainer` and after another button is click it will do that again an again etc...

How do i make a click on the ajax action link to update the entire partial view what would be the UpdateTargetId ?

I know I can create another partial that will only list the buttons and that will update a target from the parent partial but then you will have to remember to change the parent if something gets updated and that does not seem like a good design (or is it ? )..